# Question about a dog collar

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I have a question about what evidence there is for claims made by a company for a dog collar that treats certain things affecting your dog. I think on the Pet SE (for pet owners, breeders, caretakers, veterinarians and trainers) there would likely be many people interested in such a question and any evidence about its efficacy (maybe people more than here), but I'm not sure about anecdotes and the how skeptical the contributors will be about available information, stories heard from friends, or even recommendations made by vets on Youtube, etc. I suppose if it was a site solely for veterinarians (who by definition are physicians and practice medicine) I may be more assured in the answers given. (This is no impugnment/impugning/impugnation of the standards on that site or the non-veterinarians on that site).

Would such a question, when what I am looking for is actual evidence, be a more appropriate question here or at the Pet SE?

Comment: Ask away.  If there is a claim made by the manufacturer it should be verifiable.

Comment: Just fyi, if it's embedded *with medicine*, it probably works (or at least does *something*). If it's embedded with crystals or magnets, it almost certainly doesn't have any effect on the pet other than looking snazzy and/or sticking to metal objects

Comment: @Richard Supposedly it works on "pheromones". It's also very expensive and it might be tapping into the "I don't have a clue if it works but nothing's too good for my dog" market or - for those less well off - the "I'll believe anything" market. Then again, it may be legit. It's funny it makes claims about "scientifically proven" and "research" but never mentions one paper. It also doesn't go anywhere beyond "pheromones" as its active component.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the question would be acceptable on both - but only some of the potential answers would be acceptable here. (Anecdotes would not be.)

(I wrote this as an answer so I could give you some tips about quoting a single specific claim, with references to show that people believed it, but then I noticed your rep and question history, and realised you've got this!)

Comment: Thanks. I'm tempted to ask it there because 1) There are likely people there that also really want to know (maybe they use it); and 2) I'd be interested to know how many people believe it (if there's no good evidence). I actually support alternative medicine in some ways because of the placebo effect, but on a dog I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.

Comment: The placebo effect is widely misunderstood, and may not be as advantageous as you think, but that's a question for another place.